# Function unpack() shows different results

Tags: php

I'm trying to unpack hex 4-bytes to float:

```
var_dump(unpack("f", "\x3c\x6b\x2c\x45"));
```

But when i execute in cli and via web i get different results.

- Via cli: `float(2758.7021484375)`
- Via web: `float(3.3106399961764E+21)`

phpversion() returns `5.3.10-1ubuntu3.7`

Why?

Comment: Show us outputs as well for faster and more useful answers. ;)

Comment: What does `phpversion()` return?

Comment: Format `'f'` has machine dependent size and representation (see [`pack()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.pack.php)). Did you try both on the same machine?

Comment: Yes, both on the same machine. Question updated.

Comment: Do web and cli use the same php bin? Try to call with the corresponding bin or better: with the same php.ini file.

Comment: If you use HEX converter from this page: http://www.h-schmidt.net/FloatConverter/ and set your float via hex (0x452c6b3c - reversed your input), you get same result as for CLI.
There is no way to get "web" output from your values. Even if you reverse the bit and/or byte order